# Powershell startup script to login to website acting differently on restart

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, startup

I have a powershell script I'm running on startup to open a website and log in. It works fine whenever I run the script manually, or whenever I sign out of my profile in Windows and sign back in. However, when I restart the computer, the script opens the website, but then fails to edit the DOM to change the username and password text fields and click the submit button. It seems to attempt to change the values because the cursor stops blinking, but nothing happens.

Here is the code.

```
$IEProcess = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("iexplore", "-k https://www.website.com")
Sleep -Seconds 1
$IE = $(New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").Windows() | ? {$_.HWND -eq $IEProcess.MainWindowHandle}

while ($IE.ReadyState -ne 4)
{
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

$IE.Document.getElementById(“userNameInput”).value = $Username 
$IE.Document.getElementByID(“passwordInput”).value= $Password 
$IE.Document.getElementById(“submitButton”).Click()
```

Comment: Startup scripts run in the system context not the user context. Make it a logon script.

Comment: I meant to say logon script. I'm running it through the gpo logon scripts.

Comment: sounds like you need to put some logging in there to see what the values of those variables actually are when it is running.

Answer (score 1):

Using this code, I was able to get it to work. It may have to do with how you are configuring it to run on startup.

```
$Url = "https://stackoverflow.com/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=https%3a% 
2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2f" 

$Username="name@email.com"

$Password="password" 

$IE = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$IE.visible = $true; 
$IE.navigate($url); 

while ($IE.Busy -eq $true) 

{ 

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 2000; 

} 

$IE.Document.getElementById("email").value = $Username 
$IE.Document.getElementByID("password").value=$Password 
$IE.Document.getElementById("submit-button").Click()
```

I did the following:

1. Open gpedit.msc
2. User config > Windows Settings > Scripts (Logon/Logoff)
3. "PowerShell Scripts" tab
4. Add script

Comment: I need to open internet explorer in kiosk mode.